# Pandas - How to extract columns from a dataframe using another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I am looking to extract columns from a dataframe using another dataframe. I don't want to hard code the column headers into the code as the data comes from a csv and columns can be added with different headers. Tried with .loc and using iterations, but nothing seems to work.  This is what I have for code which are all from two different csv documents...

df1 =

```
    Date     a   b   c  d
 11/11/2011  2   3   4  5
 11/12/2011  3   4   5  6
 11/13/2011  4   5   6  7
```

df1 was translated using a .pivot and a,b,c,d's column header is Symbol
and

df2=

```
Symbol
    b
    d
```

The expect outcome is...

```
     b   d
 x   3   5
 y   4   6
 z   5   7
```

Tried doing

```
df1.loc(df2)
```

but got a 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed error

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
In [157]: df1[df2['Symbol']]
Out[157]: 
   b  d
0  3  5
1  4  6
2  5  7
```

Comment: You answered 5 seconds before me :)

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel Haha. Sorry bout that. ;)

Comment: I have removed mine as they are alike